# GET_ACCOUNTS Permission, Email Privacy

Tags: email, privacy

Any app with the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission, may retrieve all registered accounts and email addresses stored in Account Manager. I understand this imposes serious privacy and security issues, as a phone compromised with a potentially malicious app, could have ALL of their email addresses collected, and sent to unintended parties.

To tackle this issue, I know one could be prudent in choosing the apps I install, and use a 3rd party email app that **does not** use the Android account manager to store account/email credentials. However, there do not seem to be many of such email apps available to choose from. Most of them use the Android account manager, including of course the stock email app.

My question is, what are the best ways to tackle this issue? Since the choices one have is extremely limited.

Answer (score 0):

You can deny permissions requested by apps when using Android 6+ in Settings --> Apps (or Apps & notifications) --> Your_app --> Permissions.

However if you are "forced" into accepting the permissions that may infringe on your privacy, it is better if you have a rooted phone or tablet to install apps that can feed them with fake data. Thus, reducing their ability to access your private information.